# Real-time listener doesn't work in PWA with Pusher

Tags: node.js, reactjs, server, progressive-web-apps, pusher

I'm trying to build [my first PWA](https://pusher.com/tutorials/pwa-react). I managed to do [it](https://floating-headland-30584.herokuapp.com/), however, pushers functionality for some reason doesn't work.

I was debugging this for a few hours now and I can't make it work. I already tried rebuilding the app several times.

So, I'm subscribing to this

```
 this.prices = this.pusher.subscribe('coin-prices');
```

then I have this function

```
  sendPricePusher(data) {
    console.log('Sending data from React')
    console.log(data)
    axios.post('/prices/new', {
      prices: data
    })
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response)
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error)
      })
  }
```

I'm calling the function above every 10 seconds from my

```
componentDidMount()
setInterval(() => {
      axios.get('https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/pricemulti?fsyms=BTC,ETH,LTC&tsyms=USD')
        .then(response => {
          this.sendPricePusher(response.data)
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.log(error)
        })
    }, 10000)
```

NodeJs handles it perfectly. I see 200 in dev console.

```
app.post('/prices/new', (req, res) => {

    // Trigger the 'prices' event to the 'coin-prices' channel
    pusher.trigger( 'coin-prices', 'prices', {
        prices: req.body.prices
    });

    res.sendStatus(200);
})
```

For some reason this magic piece of code doesn't work.

```
this.prices.bind('prices', price => {
  this.setState({ btcprice: price.prices.BTC.USD });
  this.setState({ ethprice: price.prices.ETH.USD });
  this.setState({ ltcprice: price.prices.LTC.USD });
}, this);
```

It should recreate the state and the values will be updated.

So, I came to the conclusion that something is wrong with my server code.  I want to host the app on heroku. I tried to write different variations of servers but none of them seem to work. However, I'm not 100% sure that my server is the problem. Can you please have a look at my server code? Here's my **server.js** file and [a link](https://github.com/frkntony/stackoverflow-pwa) to the project on github in case the problem is not so obvious. Pusher seems like a cool tech. I want to keep using it in my future projects just need to understand how.

```
// server.js
const express = require('express')
const path = require('path')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const app = express()
const Pusher = require('pusher')
const HTTP_PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

//initialize Pusher with your appId, key, secret and cluster
const pusher = new Pusher({
    appId: '593364',
    key: '8d30ce41f530c3ebe6b0',
    secret: '8598161f533c653455be',
    cluster: 'eu',
    encrypted: true
})

// Body parser middleware
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
app.use(express.static("build"));

// CORS middleware
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    // Website you wish to allow to connect
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
    // Request methods you wish to allow
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE')
    // Request headers you wish to allow
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type')
    // Set to true if you need the website to include cookies in the requests sent
    // to the API (e.g. in case you use sessions)
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true)
    // Pass to next layer of middleware
    next()
})

// API route in which the price information will be sent to from the clientside
app.post('/prices/new', (req, res) => {
    // Trigger the 'prices' event to the 'coin-prices' channel
    pusher.trigger( 'coin-prices', 'prices', {
        prices: req.body.prices
    });
    res.sendStatus(200);
})


app.use((req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + "/build/index.html"));
  });

app.listen(HTTP_PORT, err => {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err)
    } else {
        console.log('Server runs on ' + HTTP_PORT)
    }
  })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good way to distinguish if the problem is in your server or Pusher's functionality is to test the Pusher part of the code separately with dummy data to ensure that at least the Publish/Subscribe functionality is working fine, i.e you have set it up as expected.

So you could just try the following in separate files:

```
//publisher
pusher.trigger( 'coin-prices', 'prices', {
        prices: dummyprices
});


//subscriber
var prices = pusher.subscribe('coin-prices');
prices.bind('prices', ({ price }) => {
  console.log(price);
})
```

Assuming you have initialized the Pusher SDKs correctly, this should work, if so, then the Pusher side of things is just fine and you can concentrate on finding out what in your server is causing the app to not work.

btw, in your existing code, you might wanna change:

```
this.prices.bind('prices', price => {})
```

to

```
this.prices.bind('prices', ({ price }) => {})
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. So, I tested my app. The problem is that it doesn't respond to my channel. this.prices.bind('prices', ({price}) => {
  this.setState({ btcprice: price.prices.BTC.USD });
  this.setState({ ethprice: price.prices.ETH.USD });
  this.setState({ ltcprice: price.prices.LTC.USD });
}, this); My app sends data to my node server - all good here. My node server recieves data and triggers 'pusher.trigger' with right data. However, my app doesn't trigger the room subscription even for some reason. I subscribed to the channel but it's not responding at all.

Comment: I fixed it! After I realized that the problem was with my pusher setup I recreated the instance. Everything worked. So, I went to back to my code and the main problem was that I used app_id instead of key in my pusher setup. Thanks a lot for your little unit test. I'll be sure to check ably realtime for my next project as well :)).